# Error calling Javascript object from another file

Tags: javascript, object

I have created a new client.messages2.js file containing only the functions I want to use and rewrote these functions based on Jonathan's suggestions:

```
var clientMessages = function(){
var self = this;

self.message = function (type) {
    var that = {};
    that.type = type;
    return that;
};

self.request = function (type) {
    var that = message(type);
    return that;
};

self.request = function (type) {
    var that = message(type);
    return that;
};

self.requestConfiguration = function (type, params) {
    var that = request(type);
    [...some code here...]
    return that;
};

self.requestGetConfiguration = function (params) {
    var that = requestConfiguration("RequestGetConfiguration", params);
    return that;
};

self.requestSetConfiguration = function (params) {
    var that = requestConfiguration("RequestSetConfiguration", params);
    return that;
};
}
var clientMessages = new clientMessages();
```

The following files are loaded in the html file:

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='lib/jquery-1.11.3.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='lib/require.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='scripts/clientlibs/client.messages2.js') }}"></script>
```

The code in main.js is:

```
var clientMessages = require(["/static/scripts/clientlibs/client.message2.js"]);
var request = clientMessages.requestGetConfiguration({});
```

I've also tried requestGetConfiguration without brackets:

```
var clientMessages = require(["/static/scripts/clientlibs/client.message2.js"]);
var request = clientMessages.requestGetConfiguration;
```

In the first case I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: clientMessages.requestGetConfiguration is not a function

In both cases I get the following:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (NOT FOUND) require.js:8 Uncaught Error: Script error for
>   "/static/scripts/clientlibs/client.message2.js"
>   http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror

Please note that I can see and edit the client.message2.js when I go to Inspect in Chrome. It is under localhost:5000/static/scripts/clientlibs/client.message2.js

Comment: Sounds like a scope problem. You'll probably have to provide more code so we can figure out what scope "var request" is located in.

Comment: I have added more code, hopeit is more clear now.

Comment: In the last line of your code you overwrite your constructor function clientMessages by the instantiatin of clientMessages... and also you use the same (global?) in the require() line...

Comment: @fast, so the last line should be omitted?

Comment: At least.. i'm not sure, if the code is a valid require.js module... Generally, be carefull when using same identifiers for different things, better use different ones, until you are very sure :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a scope problem.

Because of prefix `var` your function requestSetConfiguration is private.

To make a public function, try to use something like:

```
var self = this;
self.clientMessages { ...
```

An example how to do it:

clientMessages.js: (look, I change the file name)

```
var ClientMessages = function(){
   var self = this;
   self.requestSetConfiguration = function(params){...};
}
var clientMessages = new ClienteMessages();
```

main.js: (first you have to import the clientMessages.js and the main.js in your html file or require clientMessages.js in main.js with some [AMD](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html) implementation)

```
...
clientMessages.requestSetConfiguration(params);
```

Comment: Do you mean in the client.messages.js should be like:


`define(["./client.parameters"],
    function (clientParameters) {
        var self = this;
 self.clientMessages = {`


Because I did it and it didn't work...

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I cannot make it work. I followed your suggestion and added require.js and then in my main I added the following code:

`require(["./libs/client.messages.js"], function(clientMessages) {
        var request = clientMessages.requestGetConfiguration;
    });`
the result is an error message "require is not defined". I also tried with define but the error message was the same ("define is not defined").

Comment: It is also strange that even without require my IDE recognises the clientMessages object and when I CTRL+click it redirects me to the right function. But the code cannot recognise it.

Comment: Do you add your require.js in your html file? something like <script data-main="app/main" src="app/vendor/requirejs/require.js"></script> and I suggest you follow this require sintax: var clientMessages = require("./libs/clientMessages");

Comment: I am sorry but it doesn't work. I have updated my question with the code as it is now, based on your suggestions. I have also added the errors I get now.